# how to add background images using css in phonegap

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am making a tab for mobile device in phonegap. I want to add image as background for the tabs. The problem is that it does not add any background image. here is my directory structure

images are in this folder

```
www/img/tabs.png
```

In css below I am using path to images like this url(./img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat; which does not work.
here is are my css files

```
www/stylesheet/css/frames/footer.css
```

here is are all of my pages located

```
www/pages/home.html
```

and here is my css

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #535353; 
}

footer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

footer ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5% 10.9%;
    background: url(./img/tabs.png) top left no-repeat; 
}

footer ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

footer ul li a .current {
    background: url(./img/tabs.png) bottom left no-repeat; 
}
```

here is my html

```
<header>
    Header
</header>
<section id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroll-content">

    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photo</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your image `url` is not ok.

In fact, the `url` you provide to the path of your image should be related to the location of your CSS file.

So, you need to use:

> `url(../../../img/tabs.png)`

instead of:

> `url(./img/tabs.png)`

Have a try and let me know if this works